# Where is encfs password stored

Tags: encfs

How and where does encfs store the password for an encrypted directory?

I understand that encfs uses `encfs6.xml` to store the actual decryption key encoded using the password. I also understand that `encfs6.xml` is the only file required for decryption. I therefore assumed that the password hash should also be stored in the same file. However, I only see `encodedKeyData` and `saltData` in the file.

What I want to know is how does encfs make sure I have entered the correct password simply with the help of the information present in `encfs6.xml`

Answer (score 3):

This Q&A [how-do-decryption-algorithms-determine-whether-your-attempted-passphrase-is-correct](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15896/how-do-decryption-algorithms-determine-whether-your-attempted-passphrase-is-corr) suggest that decryption algorithms which needs to know if a passphrase is correct uses HMAC to validate the correctness of the passphrase.

> Therefore, when it's important to be able to inform the user whether a
>   decryption operation has succeeded in yielding the expected data,
>   cryptography engineers use [Message Authentication Codes](https://class.coursera.org/crypto-preview/lecture/22).
>   Hash-based MACs allow a candidate plaintext to be compared against an
>   authenticated hash value. If the check passes, then we know that it is
>   the correct plaintext and are then able to notify the user that the
>   decryption function was successful as intended.

Some info about [encfs design](https://github.com/vgough/encfs/blob/master/DESIGN.md) :

- There is volume key which is used for encrypting all file names and contents
- A user supplied password is used to decrypt a volume key

The password you provides is used in order to decrypt the volume key.

> **Technology**
>
> - Encfs uses algorithms from third-party libraries (OpenSSL is the default) to encrypt data and filenames.
> - A user supplied password is used to decrypt a volume key, and the volume key is used for encrypting all file names and contents. This
>     makes it possible to change the password without needing to re-encrypt
>     all files.

According to this [security audit](https://defuse.ca/audits/encfs.htm)

- EncFS uses the same key for encrypting data and computing MACs
- EncFS uses 64-bit MACs.
- **EncFS uses Mac-then-Encrypt**
- The purpose of MAC headers is to prevent an attacker with read/write
  access to the ciphertext from being able to make changes without being
  detected.  Unfortunately, this feature provides little security, since
  it is controlled by an option in the .encfs6.xml configuration file

*Answer to the question in comment, the MAC is being saved as part of each  encryped file.*

Comment: Even if MAC is used it would still need a hash in the xml file to compare it to. My question is where is this hash stored

Comment: @Samik - I've updated my answer, with the location of the hash

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking at encfs source it seems that the first 4 characters (bytes) of `encodedKeyData` is the hash used for HMAC validation.

https://github.com/vgough/encfs/blob/7cc6efa60ca7378ba2b95be1fe5804a97f29af10/encfs/SSL_Cipher.cpp#L530#L546

and

https://github.com/vgough/encfs/blob/7cc6efa60ca7378ba2b95be1fe5804a97f29af10/encfs/SSL_Cipher.cpp#L49